# int[][] cannot be converted to square

Tags: java, class, constructor

So I'm a bit confused on constructors and this whole class thing, but I've tried to do extensive research to try to figure it out. I am creating a class called square to do various manipulations on data files with numbers as a square. The only issue I'm having is converting an int[][] to a "Square"

```
     import java.util.Arrays;
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import java.io.*;

     public class Square {

      int row;
      int column;
      int[][] actual;




      //CONSTRUCTOR:

       public Square(){
              this.row=0;
              this.column=0;
              this.actual=null;
       }  



        //SHIFTS LEFT:
       public Square shiftLeft(int row) throws FileNotFoundException{
         File file = new File("square.txt");
         Scanner numberFile = new Scanner(file);
         int size = numberFile.nextInt();
           //creates arrays
         int[][]actualNumbers = new int[size][size];
         int[]shiftedArray = new int[size];

         String numbers = "";
       //creates orginial array from data file     
      while(numberFile.hasNextLine()){
         numbers = numberFile.nextLine();
         for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<size;j++){
               actualNumbers[i][j] = numberFile.nextInt();
                  }
               }
            }
        //shifts array 
        int lastToFirst= 0;
        int lastlast=0;
        for(int k = 0; k<size-1;k++){
              lastToFirst = actualNumbers[row-1][size-1];
              lastlast=actualNumbers[row-1][size-2];
              shiftedArray[k+1] = actualNumbers[row-1][k];
              shiftedArray[0]= lastToFirst;
              actualNumbers[row-1][actualNumbers.length-1]=lastlast; 
              actualNumbers[row-1][k]=shiftedArray[k];

        }

      return actualNumbers;
      }  



        //SHIFTS DOWN:

      public Square shiftDown(int column) throws FileNotFoundException {
      File file = new File("square.txt");
      Scanner numberFile = new Scanner(file);
      int size = numberFile.nextInt();
      //creates new array 
      int[][]actualNumbers = new int[size][size];
      int[]shiftedArray = new int[size];

      String numbers = "";
       //puts data file into array      
      while(numberFile.hasNextLine()){
         numbers = numberFile.nextLine();
         for (int i=0; i< size;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<size;j++){
               actualNumbers[i][j] = numberFile.nextInt();
                  }
               }
            } 
       //shifts array 
         int startToLast = 0;
         int lastlast=0;
         for(int k=0; k<size-1; k++){
              startToLast = actualNumbers[size-1][column-1];
              lastlast=actualNumbers[size-2][column-1];
              shiftedArray[k+1] = actualNumbers[k][column-1];
              shiftedArray[0]= startToLast;
              actualNumbers[actualNumbers.length-1][column-1]=lastlast; 
              actualNumbers[k][column-1]=shiftedArray[k];


         }
         return actualNumbers;        
           }

        //FLIPS NUMBERS:        
       public Square flipSide(int row)throws FileNotFoundException{
         File file = new File("square.txt");
         Scanner numberFile = new Scanner(file);
         int size = numberFile.nextInt();
         //creates new array 
         int[][]actualNumbers = new int[size][size];
         String numbers = "";
         //puts data file into array      
         while(numberFile.hasNextLine()){
            numbers = numberFile.nextLine();
            for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
               for(int j=0; j<size;j++){
               if(numberFile.hasNextInt()){
                  actualNumbers[i][j] = numberFile.nextInt();
                  }
               }
               }
               }
               System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(actualNumbers));
               System.out.println();
               int[] isolatedArray = new int[size];
               int[] flippedArray = new int[size];
               for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
               isolatedArray[i]=actualNumbers[row-1][i];
               }

               for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
               flippedArray[j]=isolatedArray[isolatedArray.length-j-1];
               }          

               for(int k=0; k<size; k++){
               actualNumbers[row-1][k]=flippedArray[k];
               }

               System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(actualNumbers));
               return actualNumbers;
               }       
    }
```

Comment: `shiftLeft` method return type is `Square`, but the method tries to return `actualNumbers` which is `int[][]`. The method return type should be the same as the returned object.

Comment: And your code is not indented properly, which makes it very hard to grasp. Learn to indent your code, and read the Java tutorial about classes, fields, methods, constructors. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Answer (score 0):

An int[][] is of course not yet a Square object, but you're returning it as if it is. You could for example change the constructor of Square to:

```
Public Square (int[][] act) {
    actual = act;
    ....
```

Then you'll have to do some extra calculations to get the row and column fields to what you want them to be (I don't know).

But then in the shiftDown function, instead of returning actualNumbers, you can use:

```
return New Square(actualNumbers);
```